# Partition data into two sets of the same size such that the sum of the average distances is maximized

Tags: algorithms, heuristics, partitions

Say I have a set of strings $S=\{s_1, s_2, ..., s_N\}$, and I want to partition $S$ into two sets $S_1$ and $S_2$ equally, i.e., $||S_1|-|S_2||\leq1$.

Define the difference of a set as
$$Diff(S_k)=\frac{\displaystyle{\sum_{s_i,s_j\in S_k} d(s_i,s_j)}}{\displaystyle{|S_k|\choose 2}}$$

where $d(s_i,s_j)$ is a custom distance function that calculates the 'distance' between two strings, satisfying $d(s_i,s_j)=d(s_j,s_i)$.

The objective is to find a partition of $S$ that maximize $Diff(S_1)+Diff(S_2)$, assuming we already have $d(s_i,s_j)$ for $s_i,s_j\in S$.

Are there any (heuristic) algorithms that I can use to achieve the objective?
Or maybe this problem can be generalized to some known problem with loose constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us call this problem $P$. Assuming we can choose the fucntion $d$ freely, this problem is NP-hard. I willl show a proof sketch for the case where $N$ is even. This already implies that the problem in general is NP-hard. The proof is a reduction from the **balanced cut problem**.

Let us define the function $\operatorname{Diff}'(S_k) = \sum\limits_{s_i, s_j \in S_k} d(s_i, s_j)$. Let $P'$ be the same problem defined over $\operatorname{Diff}'$ instead of $\operatorname{Diff}$, i.e. the goal is to find a partition that maximizes $\operatorname{Diff}'(S_1) + \operatorname{Diff}'(S_2)$. Claerly, for an even value of $N$, a solution $(S_1, S_2)$ is optimal for $P$ if and only if it is optimal for $P'$, since $|S_1| = |S_2|$, and hence the problems $P$ and $P'$ are equivalent. We now procede with the problem $P'$.

It is quite easy to reduce the balanced cut problem (defined below) to this problem. Intuitively, let us represent the input as a complete weighted graph, where the strings correspond to vertices and the function $d$ correspond to the weight of the edges. Our goal is to partition the vertices of this graph into two sets $(S_1, S_2)$ in a way that maximizes the total sum of weights of edges in both induced subgraphs $G[S_1]$ and $G[S_2]$. This is equivalent to minimizing the weight of the cut $(S_1, S_2)$, since each edge belongs to either one of the induced subgraphs or is a cut edge. Hence, we aim to find a partition of the vertices into two sets of equal sizes in a way that minimizes the weight of the cut. That is exatly the definition of the weighted balanced cut problem.

```
Balanced cut problem
Input: An undirected graph $G$.
Asked: A partition of $V(G)$ into two sets $(S_1, S_2)$ of equal sizes,
minimizing the size of the cut $(S_1, S_2)$.
```

This problem is NP-hard, and hence, the weighted version as well. Now it is not hard to reduce the weighted version of this problem to $P'$. Given a graph $G$ with a weight function $w$, we first add all missing edges as edges with weight zero. Now we build a string $s_v$ for each vertex $v$ and set $d(s_u, s_v) = w(u, v)$ for w the given weight function of $G$. Cearly this instance of $P'$ admits a parition of weight $k$ if and only if $G$ admits a balanced cut of cost $W - k$, where $W = \sum_{e \in E(G)} w(e)$.